# Using python type hints as runtime type checking (raise TypeError if different)

Tags: python, types, assert, type-hinting, python-typing

I have an example function:

```py
from typing import Dict


def cool_func(foo: Dict[object, str], bar: bool, baz: float) -> None:
    foo_type_error_msg = "foo must be a Dict[object, str]"
    if not foo.isinstance(dict):
        raise TypeError(foo_type_error_msg)
    for s in foo.values():
        if not s.isinstance(str):
            raise TypeError(foo_type_error_msg)

    # the rest of the function
```

How can I use the type specified in the type hints to check the variable at runtime? Please note that I don't want to be strict on other variables (just check the `foo` parameter).

In case you wonder, I want to enforce the type so that the error (caused by the wrong Type) won't appear somewhere in `the rest of the function` and confuse the user with the default error message.

I wish that I can have something like this:

```py
def cool_func(foo: Dict[object, str], bar: bool, baz: float) -> None:
    check_type('foo')
    # the rest of the function
```

or at least

```py
def cool_func(foo: Dict[object, str], bar: bool, baz: float) -> None:
    check_type(foo, 'Dict[object, str]')
    # the rest of the function
```

Comment: http://mypy-lang.org/

Comment: Hmm, I don't want to check the code internally. The feature I need is for it to raise error when the code is used as a module or in some other script.

Comment: Honestly, the best bet is to probably just implement the runtime check yourself. There *are* libraries like [Typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard) that let you do checks at runtime, but I'm not sure they have a way of letting you check just a single argument. And even if they do, it's a fairly heavy dependency for just a single check.